# expo-cli Errors on fresh installation

Tags: react-native, expo

I ran the following commands as in the documentation to get started:

```
$ yarn global add expo-cli
$ expo init myNewProject
$ cd myNewProject
$ expo start
```

Got the following errors

```
Error: Invalid sdkVersion. Valid options are 7.0.0, 8.0.0, 9.0.0, 10.0.0, 11.0.0, 12.0.0, 13.0.0, 14.0.0, 15.0.0, 16.0.0, 17.0.0, 18.0.0, 19.0.0, 20.0.0, 21.0.0, 22.0.0, 23.0.0, 24.0.0, 25.0.0, 26.0.0, 27.0.0, 28.0.0, 29.0.0, 30.0.0, 31.0.0, 32.0.0, 33.0.0, 34.0.0, 35.0.0, 36.0.0, 37.0.0, 38.0.0, 39.0.0
error: unknown option `--assetExts'

Metro Bundler process exited with code 1
```

Than I added `"sdkVersion": "39.0.0",` to `app.json.expo`, ran `$ expo start` again and the second error still remains:

```
error: unknown option `--assetExts'

Metro Bundler process exited with code 1
```

Running `$ EXPO_DEBUG=true expo start` gives the following:

```
Metro Bundler process exited with code 1
Error: Metro Bundler process exited with code 1
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/@expo/xdl@56.2.7/src/Project.ts:1804:16)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:284:20)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:196:13)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:256:12)
```

my `app.json` is:

```
{
  "name": "reactNativeExpo",
  "displayName": "React Native Expo",
  "expo": {
    "name": "reactNativeExpo",
    "slug": "expo-template-bare",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "sdkVersion": "39.0.0",
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"]
  }
}
```

My system info

```
$ yarn global list expo
yarn global v1.21.1
info "expo-cli@3.27.13" has binaries:
   - expo
   - expo-cli

$ npm -v
6.14.8

$ node -v
v12.0.0
```

Again this is a fresh installation, I haven't done anything except the steps I outlined above.

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

upgrading node to `12.13.0` did the trick. Opened an [issue](https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/2760) in expo-cli to suggest documentation for that